# pygame not finding .tff file when it is there

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I was trying to load a font in pygame to render some simple text. I tried importing a font I had downloaded. The font is named hack.tff, and it's in `assets/fonts/`.

```
hack = pygame.font.Font('assets/fonts/hack.tff', 30)
```

But, strangely, when running the code, it returns a error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

I ran the code through cmd and opening the .py file. The cmd is on the same directory as the .py file

Comment: I suspect the working directory from where you launch your application isn't what you think it is. Relative paths will be relative to the current working directory. You may want to expand this question with how your are launching the program.

Comment: I tried both cmd (I am on the game dir) and opening the .py file directly.

Comment: Ttf vs tff? I think you had the extension wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try './assets/fonts/hack.tff' or a complete path name such as,
os.path.abspath( './assets/fonts/hack.tff' )